# How to migrate deep links in a SPA?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, ngrx

Let's say the current link is:

https://[server]/param1/param2/param3 where param3 represents an entity in the system.
https://[server]/area1/area2/12345

Now let's say due to a design decision, all entities that are param3 are swapped out with different values.
So: https://[server]/area1/area2/12345-abcde would be the same entity but new identity in the system.

This invalidates all user bookmarks due to using NgRx RouteSerializer that takes param3 and asserts that as state, but would end up with a faulty route(12345) would just end up redirecting to the default route.

I thought maybe doing an API call inside RouteSerializer to do a lookup of the legacy value to retrieve the new entity ID, but that wouldn't work because it's an asynchronous call that only gets resolved after the RouteSerializer.serialize() has already returned.

The bigger question is how do you migrate deep links when the entity ID value changes like this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

setup a new API and version it, so the old routes are set as the default, and all new schemes moving forward get prefixed with a version key, or perhaps employ headers to set/detect version.

Otherwise you may need to capture both schemes in two stand alone routers, with the new routes setup as a fallback. And you can join the routers through a reducer or or some other mechanism

You could also put in place a rewrites list, which would capture the old signatures and rewrite them to the new scheme